# dividend cash in month

Tags: dividends

I like know how much money dividend cash I get. For example I own two shares of the stock dividend cash will be **4.54$** ?

```
Prev Close: 52.01
Open:   51.85
Bid:    48.28 x 200
Ask:    52.75 x 100
1y Target Est:  49.44
Beta:   0.41
Next Earnings Date: 29-Apr-15O Earnings announcement
Day's Range:    51.54 - 52.64
52wk Range: 39.62 - 55.54
Volume: 1,579,416
Avg Vol (3m):   2,294,020
Market Cap: 11.76B
P/E (ttm):  50.13
EPS (ttm):  1.04
Div & Yield:    2.27 (4.50%)
```

Comment: This site is dedicated to quantitative finance professionals, see [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that the Dividend stated in your figures represents how much dividend you will be receiving in a month.  However, you need to know exactly what that field represents.  It could be one of the following:

1. Annualised dividend (most recent dividend multiplied by frequency... eg. quarterly dividend multipled by 4)
2. Annualised declared dividend (most recent declared by not yet entitled/paid dividend multiplied by frequency)
3. Trailing twelve month dividend (all dividends received in the last 12 months)
4. Annual dividend - all dividends allocated to the most recent complete fiscal year
5. Some other derivation (perhaps based the sum of dividends included in quarterly reports)

Every dividend declared by the company has one important date - the ex-date.  If you have bought on or before the close of the previous trading date then you are entitled to that dividend.  If you purchase after the close of the previous trading date (e.g. after-hours trading) or any time on or after the ex-date then you are NOT entitled to that dividend.  Note that the date you get paid the dividend is typically a few weeks after the ex-date but this can vary.  Note also that you can sell the stock on the ex-date and still receive the dividend.  You should be learn which different taxation rules applicable to stock holding periods on dividends.

With a bit of sleuthing, I found a stock that matches your data.  I assume you are referring to the stock NYSE:O (Realty Income REIT).  This company historically pays out dividends on a monthly basis.  The most recent dividend declared is 0.1895 with an ex-date of Monday 30 Mar 2015.  You need to be holding the stock by the close of Friday 27 Mar 2015.  The payment date for the dividend is 15 Apr 2015.  In answer to your question, you will receive a dividend for 2 shares * 0.1895 = 0.379

The dividend value 2.27 in your figures appears to represent the annualised dividend of the most recently declared dividend of 0.1895 * 12 and therefore assumes the dividends will remain constant for the next 12 months.

A sample of prior dividends for NYSE:O, by ex-date, are:

`20150226 0.1890
20150129 0.1890
20141230 0.183417
20141126 0.183104
20141030 0.183104
20140929 0.183104
20140828 0.182792
20140730 0.182792
20140627 0.182792
20140529 0.182479
20140429 0.182479
20140328 0.182479
20140227 0.182167
20140130 0.182167
20141230 0.182167`

Data for this exercise came from Premium Data.  Disclosure: I am a co-owner of Premium Data.